# Is there any event for body change?

Tags: javascript, api, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

As i know in Jquery there are .change() event for any textbox is there any way to access body textbox?

Or is there any build in event for Office.context.mailbox.item?

ref 
https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html

Comment: yes, i want to get body content to process and show some validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at the moment there's no event to be notified of body changes. You can poll every few seconds (3-5) to request it though.

Comment: so sad this api is so limited